# @property in vue components

Tags: vue.js, frontend, storage

[image]

I am on the project with Vue.js, and it's the first time I see that type of thing @property etc. Can anyone explain to me what this thing is?

P.S. with global search I cannot find references in my project folder, so don't know where it's derived from

I just tried to search the property name with Ctrl+Shift+F inside the project folder. That's about it. Just want to know something about this pattern.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docblock

Comment: You may have vue-styleguidist installed in your project, which uses JSDoc tags to document your components. @property is one of the tags provided by JSDoc, more information about it [here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-property.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just documenting the component arguments/properties.

[From the docunentation](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/docs/Documenting.html#events):

> If your event returns arguments/properties use the @property tag to describe them

```
/**
 * Triggers when the number changes
 *
 * @property {number} newValue new value set
 * @property {number} oldValue value that was set before the change
 */

this.$emit('change', newValue, oldValue)
```